# File operations working in AppletViewer but not Browser

Tags: java, applet, file-handling

I am working on an applet which will save details and read it later in a new session opened by the user. I have a `data.txt` file in my bin folder and I am using this  to access it

```
URL url = this.class.getResource("/data.txt");
FileOutputStream foStream=new FileOutputStream(url.getFile());
```

It runs as expected in the Eclipse AppletViewer, but not in the Mozilla Firefox browser(file operations aren't working) . Seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768938/java-bufferedimage-works-in-appletviewer-but-not-browser) , I packaged my code in a jar and certified it as well. It still isn't working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again. *"I packaged my code in a jar and certified it as well"* Using your own certificate ('self signed') or using a certificate obtained from a Certification Authority?

Comment: I will enable the Java console as you said and try..I have self-signed my certificate.Is the problem due to that?

Comment: *"Is the problem due to that?"* Most likely. The console will know better than my guesses though.